# Cannot access Shared File in LAN but WAN

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, network-share, local-area-network

I could not access my Shared File in LAN but if I use public IP address, it can be accessed. Can anyone give me hints? Both machine are Win server 2012R2

[This is an error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLo0u.png)

Comment: @ Rex          That server has private IP address (192.168.55.77) and public IP address (X), I can access X via File Explorer (\\X\sharefolder) but cannot via \\192.168.55.77\sharefolder  This screenshot is showing error in LAN IP address

Comment: When I use public address, I can access the share folder, don't u understand?